# Understanding .bashrc and .bash_profile

Tags: bash, alias

On a server when I login as root I see `.bashrc` (Ubuntu 10.10).

On my Mac I have a `.bash_profile`

Does Ubuntu always have only a `.bashrc` file and not `.bash_profile`? (I'm just confused, so asking, I realize they are different o/s's but maybe there is a relationship somehow?)

On my server, I want to create an alias, should I put it in `.bashrc`?

What if I want this alias to be applied so all users can use it?

Comment: possibly duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1528/bashrc-or-bash-profile -- I'd recommend you to change your question to just ask where to put aliases globally.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Bash aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) should go in the `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` files in individual home directories. If you must create global bash aliases, they can go in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but it is often best simply to add them to the `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` files in `/etc/skel` so they are inherited by newly created users.

It is *virtually always wrong* to define an alias in in `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `/etc/profile`.

To understand why, one must understand under what circumstances commands from [each of these files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) are run. There are misconceptions about this, which I address below.

Even though you want to define aliases for multiple users, you should be familiar with how they are defined for individual users, so that you can decide on the best method of doing what you need.

### Aliases for Individual Users

Especially if you use a GUI, most of your interactive shells are probably *non-login* shells. Even if you never use a GUI, you probably still use *non-login* shells with some frequency. You'll want your aliases to work in these shells.

Especially if you ever log in non-graphically in a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) or [via SSH](https://askubuntu.com/tags/ssh/info), you probably use login shells some of the time. So you'll want your aliases to work in interactive login shells also.

**When an interactive, non-login shell starts**, it sources `.bashrc` in the user's home directory. By default in Ubuntu, each user's `.bashrc` itself sources `.bash_aliases`, if it exists.

- To *source* a file is to cause its contents to be run in the *current* shell. Changes to the shell environment made in a file that is sourced persist even after all the commands in the file have been run.

Reading the comments in Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` reveals that it is *officially intended* that aliases go in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`. `.bashrc` already contains some alias definitions (run `grep '^[[:blank:]]*alias' ~/.bashrc` to see them), and gives explicit advice about where to put new such definitions:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

**But what about interactive *login* shells?** Instead of `.bashrc`, login shells source `.profile`.

- ...Unless `.bash_login` exists, then it gets sourced instead.
- ...Unless `.bash_profile` exists, then *it* gets sourced instead.

However, the good news is that by default in Ubuntu, **commands in `.bashrc` will *also* run in interactive login shells** because the default `.profile` checks if the current shell is bash (and if `.bashrc` exists), and if so, sources `.bashrc`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

I suggest users define new bash aliases in `.bash_aliases` in their home directories (creating it if it doesn't already exist). This is a particularly clean and simple way to make alias definitions permanent at the per-user level.

**Aliases should *not* be defined in `.profile`** because they would remain undefined in non-login shells. Unlike much of a bash shell's environment, aliases are *not* exported to child shells:

```
ek@Io:~$ alias hi='echo "Greetings, $USER!"'
ek@Io:~$ hi
Greetings, ek!
ek@Io:~$ bash
ek@Io:~$ hi
hi: command not found
```

In particular, by default most desktop environments cause `.profile` to be sourced on graphical login, but:

1. This is not necessarily done by a bash shell, so alias definitions may not even be processed, *and more importantly*
2. even if alias definitions are processed, *they are not passed on to child processes*. Particularly, they are not passed on to shells created by opening a Terminal window!

**Aliases should not be defined in `.bash_profile` (or `.bash_login`)** for the very same reason, but also for another reason. Naively creating one of these files and putting *just* alias definitions in it prevents any of the code in `.profile` from running!

In situations where `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` really is useful, typically one sources `.profile` somewhere in them, which solves that problem. (Then the only remaining problem is that, like with `.profile`, defining aliases in `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` doesn't work right.)

### Aliases for *New* Individual Users, Automatically

When a user account of the type intended to represent a real human being is created, a new directory is typically made to serve as their home directory. The contents of `/etc/skel` are then copied to their home directory. This is how multiple users start out with some similar configuration files in their home directories. In Ubuntu, this includes `.profile`, `.bashrc`, and some other files.

To change what aliases are defined for new users, you can simply put them in `/etc/skel/.bash_aliases` (you will have to create it) or `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

If you edit an already-existing file in `/etc/skel` you may want to back it up first--but you shouldn't put the backup in `/etc/skel`, or it, too, will be copied into new users' home directories.

This is likely the best way for you to add new aliases for multiple users. Existing users can simply add the aliases themselves. If you define the aliases in `/etc/skel/.bash_aliases`, you can simply direct them to that file, which they may choose to copy into their home directories (or add into their own custom `.bash_aliases` file).

It's trivial for a user to undefine an alias. Additionally, [aliases are not extremely robust](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases); they work only in particular circumstances. If you need to create a new command that works *all the time, for everyone*, you should not implement that command as an alias. And you cannot successfully force aliases on users who don't want them--they can simply `unalias` them.

### Global Aliases, for All Users

Though I advise you to avoid this approach, you *can* define aliases in the the *global* `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. They will then be defined both for interactive non-login shells and for interactive login shells. The reason is, *before* any of the files in the user's home directory are sourced:

- Login shells (and only login shells and other processes behaving like login shells) run commands from `/etc/profile` automatically.
- Only non-login shells run commands in `/etc/bash.bashrc` automatically, *but*
- Ubuntu's default `/etc/profile` checks if the running shell is bash (and if `/etc/bash.bashrc` exists) and, if so, sources `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

This is analogous to how the default per-user `.profile` sources the per-user `.bashrc` if the shell is bash (as detailed above).

Here's what the actual code for this looks like in the default `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi
```

<sup>That block also performs other tasks. Specifically, the outer `if` checks if the shell is likely to be interactive (by checking that the prompt text is non-empty), then checks if the current shell is bash and sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` if it is, and if not does some work that, for bash, is already done in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.</sup>

You should *not* define global aliases in `/etc/profile` for the same reason users should not define them in their local `.profile`s: if you do, they will be defined only for login shells, and not for their child shells.

Finally, note that, unlike the default per-user `.bashrc`, the default `/etc/bash.bashrc` file does not contain anything about aliases. It is somewhat unusual to give users aliases in a file where they cannot edit or disable them. (Of course, they still *can* do that, by overriding their definitions in their own local `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases`, or elsewhere.)

### *Further Reading*

- [Why is /etc/profile not invoked for non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells)
- [How to create a permanent “alias”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)
- [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)
- [Why must I do `. .bash_profile` every time I create a new alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109985/why-must-i-do-bash-profile-every-time-i-create-a-new-alias)

Comment: According to gnu.org, the profiles are sourced if (a) interactive -or- (b) login.  Yet, on Ubuntu 22.10, it doesn't get loaded when I open gnome-terminal - only if do `ssh localhost`.  I'm confused.  (I put an echo statement at the top to test.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's some nice [reading](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) on it.  ".bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells"

So for your alias, use .bash_profile

Comment: Putting aliases in `.bash_profile` is not correct. In Ubuntu, `.profile` (which runs for login shells) sources `.bashrc` when it's an interactive bash shell. Thus putting aliases in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`, sourced in `.bashrc`) defines them in *all* interactive bash shells. Aliases in `.bash_profile` yields [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/109985), among others. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536), [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414), [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/606882), and the default `~/.bashrc`'s comments recommending putting aliases there or in `.bash_aliases`.