# Why is /etc/profile not invoked for non-login shells?

Tags: command-line, login, bashrc

Login and non-login shell defined as:

```
su - $USER # will give you a login shell
bash # will give you a non-login shell
```

/etc/profile is not invoked for non-login shells, such as when you start konsole (kde). /etc/profile is only invoked for login shells.

Why is that? Please explain, because I like to understand the rationale of this.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

#### `/etc/profile` is invoked only for login shells because that is its specific purpose.

*If you want a command to run for interactive shells that are **not** login shells, and you're using `bash`, put it in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.*

The purpose of the "profile" files is to contain commands that ought to be run for login shells only. These files are:

- `/etc/profile`, run by all [Bourne-compatible shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell_compatible) (including [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html) and [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dash.1.html)) when started as a login shell.
- Scripts in `/etc/profile.d`.

  This is for Bourne-style shells, but it's not coded into the shell executable itself. Rather, commands in `/etc/profile` calls them. For example, on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, `/etc/profile` includes these lines:

  ```sh
  if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
      if [ -r $i ]; then
        . $i
      fi
    done
    unset i
  fi
  ```
- `.profile` in the user's home directory, run by Bourne-compatible shells when started as a login shell (unless overridden, see below).
- `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` in the user's home directory. These are ignored by shells other than `bash`. But if `.bash_profile` exists, `bash` runs it *instead of* `.profile`. If `.bash_profile` doesn't exist but `.bash_login` exists, that is run instead of `.profile`.

  (But it is common for `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login`, when it exists, to be written to *explicitly call `.profile`.)

  The benefit of shell-specific *profile* files is that they can contain commands or syntax that are only valid for that shell. For example, I can use the `[[` evaluation operator in `.bash_profile`/`.bash_login` but if I use it in `.profile` and then log in with `dash` as my shell, it will fail.

#### What Should Go In "profile" Files

"profile" files should contain commands that ought only run once, at the beginning of login. (This includes graphical logins, as they start with a login shell, too.) If a shell is interactive, the user running it is probably logged on, and so it probably has an ancestor (that started it, or started what started it, or started that, etc.) that was a login shell.

You might want to run a command only once because:

1. there is no reason to run it more than one time per login, it would be inefficient, *or*
2. it would produce an undesired result, to run it more than once per login.

As an example of the second situation, where an undesirable result would occur, consider these lines, which appear by default in every user's `~/.profile`:

```sh
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Suppose you SSH'd in, ran another shell (say, [`zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/zsh.1.html)), at some point found you wanted to temporarily go back to `bash` but keep your environment (so ran `bash` again while in `zsh`), and then ran a program like [`mc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mc.1.html) that runs a shell as part of its interface. If `bin` exists in your home folder and your username is `james`, your [`PATH`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) in the innermost shell is something like:

```
/home/james/bin:/home/james/bin:/home/james/bin:/home/james/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

That's inefficient and (much more importantly) makes it hard to understand the contents of `PATH`.

This is by no means a disaster, though. As far as I can tell, if every interactive shell sourced "profile" files, nothing terrible would happen, *in the default configuration*. However, since *the purpose of "profile" files is to contain commands to just run once per login*, a user or administrator may add commands to a profile that *must* only run when starting a login shell.

#### Where to Put Commands for Every Interactive Shell to Run

If you are using `bash`, there are files for commands that are to be run in every interactive shell:

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `.bashrc` in the user's home directory.

This is most commonly used for commands that

1. affect only the environment of the shell in which they run--not even child shells, *or*
2. ought to run even when this is not the login shell.

For example, command-line tab-completion should generally be enabled whether `bash` was the login shell. So this appears in `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

There, *1* and *2* both apply: this does not carry over to other shells run inside this one, and tab-completion should work in `bash` even if I logged in with a different shell.

#### Where to Put Commands for Login Shells and Interactive non-Login Shells

If you're using `bash` and want a command to run in login shells and interactive shells and that are not login shells, *it is generally sufficient to put it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`*. This is because, by default, `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` run them explicitly. For example, `~/.profile` has:

```sh
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        source "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

(Similarly, `/etc/profile` sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` for `bash`.)

Thus both "profile" and "rc" files run when you start an interactive `bash` shell (whether or not it's a login shell).

#### Where to Put Commands to Run in non-Interactive Shells

You probably do not want to specify any commands for all non-interactive shells to run; they would run every time a script is run (provided the script is run by the shell you configure to run them).

This can cause substantial breakage. If you're going to do this, and there is not an administrator account on the system besides the one you're using, you might want to create one; that can make it easier to fix mistakes.

In `bash`, the "rc" files are actually run *whether the shell is interactive or not*. However, at the top they say:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

So, if you need commands to run automatically even in non-interactive shells like the ones that run to execute scripts, you can add your commands *before* those lines.

#### Starting a Login Shell

Logging in starts a login shell. If you want a shell started after that to behave as a login shell, start it with the `-l` flag (stands for ***l**ogin*). For example:

- `sh -l`
- `bash -l`
- `pdksh -l`

That's the best way to start a login shell (without logging in) unless you want to start one as *another* user. Then, use:

- `sudo -i` for [`root`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (use `sudo -s` for a non-login, interactive root shell)
- `sudo -u username -i` for any user
- `su - username` for non-`root` users (use `su username` for a non-login, interactive root shell)

#### What's an *initial* login shell?

An *initial login shell* is the same as a *login shell*. Everywhere this answer says "login shell" it could say "initial login shell" (except in this section, which would already have stopped making sense).

One reason for the term *initial login shell* is that *login shell* is also used in a different sense--to identify *which program* is used as the shell that is executed by logging on. This is the sense of *login shell* used to say:

- "[OpenBSD](http://openbsd.org/)'s default login shell is [`ksh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ksh&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=); on Ubuntu, it's `bash`."
- "You can [change](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells) your login shell with [`chsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chsh.1.html)."

#### Further Reading

- ["Configuration files for shells"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files_for_shells) in ["Unix shell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (Wikipedia)
- [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html) manpage
- [Full bash manual (GNU)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)

Comment: > "profile" files should contain commands that ought only run once, at the beginning of login. (This includes graphical logins, as they start with a login shell, too.) No no no no no! It absolutely does not! All bourne-like shells only read .profile on *interactive login* shell sessions, i.e. those either started with the -i option, or those connected to a controlling terminal (neither of which are true if the shell was started by a display manager). The reason this is true is because the point of this file is to set up the user's *terminal*, not just their environment. If a display manager tr

Comment: Eliah, I've reproduced the rest of Derek's comment [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22408390#22408390) but have left the above stump so he will get your reply notification, although he will not be able to respond to that due to reputation requirements. I've given him write access to the above chatroom however.

Comment: ```In bash, the "rc" files are actually run whether the shell is interactive or not. ``` is incorrect. /etc/bash.bashrc is triggered by /etc/bash.profile.

Comment: okwap is right, rc files doesn't get invoked in non-interactive shell, [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) this is more succinct and accurate.

Comment: I found that there are cases that services, e.g. in `/etc/init.d`, sometimes call `/bin/bash` giving what should be a `nologin` user to run whats in `profile.d`. so you can check if interactive first.  https://superuser.com/questions/1343953/etc-profile-d-script-interfering-with-a-service-starting-and-considerably-dela