# Where can I put commands that I want to run for all interactive, non-login shells?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

Normally, in bash, the answer would be ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc. But unfortunately Ubuntu is sourcing these files from ~/.profile and /etc/profile respectively. So, where should I put such commands on Ubuntu?

See also [Why is /etc/profile not invoked for non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells) if you are not familiar with these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no standard place for such commands on Ubuntu (without modifying behaviour that may be considered standard on Ubuntu). Here is a work-around that I came up with:

Add this to the beginning of `/etc/profile`:

```
IS_LOGIN_SHELL=1
```

Then, in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc` test for this variable:

```
if [ -n "${IS_LOGIN_SHELL-}" ]; then
   # Put your commands here
fi
```

Hopefully the variable name won't collide with anything else and this doesn't change what other parts of Ubuntu may rely on.

Answer (score 2):

If you open your `man bash`, you can find somewhere at the line 150:

> ```
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
> reads  and  executes  commands  from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
> these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the  --norc  option.
> The  --rcfile  file option will force bash to read and execute commands
> from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.
> ```

So, you can use with confidence `~/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but I will not advice you to use this system wide file) for your purpose. And yes, in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct. As I stated in my question, Ubuntu is sourcing .bashrc from .profile. Thus commands in .bashrc are also executed for login shells.

Comment: @Seb You didn't specified nothing about login shells in your question... Than, if you have a problem because `.bashrc` is sourced from `.profile` when you enter in a login shell, just comment or delete the line from `.profile` where `.bashrc` is sourced.

Comment: Excuse me? Read the very heading of my question: "interactive, non-login shells". How much more specific can I make it? Of course I know I can edit .profile and remove the source, but I am administrating a network of 40 machines and want to keep them as close as possible to "normal ubuntu" to minimize surprises later down the track (consider release upgrades etc). So I thought I'd ask whether Ubuntu has a standard place to put commands for interactive, non-login shells. Given the lack of useful answers, it seems not.