# What goes in ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bashrc, .profile

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what belongs in `~/.profile` and what belongs in `~/.bashrc`.

From what I've read, it seems *to me* that `~/.profile` should be used for environment variables and `~/.bashrc` for aliases, functions, and the like. If I move all my `export` statements from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile`, would everything work as it should, or am I about to break something?

(Here's [my dotfiles repo](https://github.com/mdebusk/dotfiles/tree/main) if you want to look over both files.)

**EDIT 2022-06-03:** I've moved most of my environment variables from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` and have assured myself that `~/.bash_profile` sources `~/.profile`. The only environment variables I've left in `~/.bashrc` are those that only matter when I'm working in a shell, e.g., those pertaining to less, the prompts, slrn, and the like. Everything seems to be working well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is /etc/profile not invoked for non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells)

Comment: @ArturMeinild It didn't, no. I'm clear on the "login" versus "non-login" thing. As things stand in my setup, I'm pretty sure the difference isn't important. I'm only considering moving all my environment variables (except for the prompt) to my ~/.profile.

Comment: Problem I have here is when I open a terminal . profile is sourced again doubling my path. Argh.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It helps to understand which files get sourced when and *why*.

`.profile` is sourced by a login shell on startup. Typically, the only login shell you start is the one started when you log in, but you can run a login shell at any time with `bash -l`. (Also, on macOS, there is no initial login shell, so terminal emulators tend to run a login shell for each new window.)

`.profile` is an ideal place to set environment variables that can be inherited by any program started from the login shell.

`.bashrc`, on the other hand, is sourced by non-login interactive shells, such as those started by terminal windows. This is where you set things *specific* to your interactive shell that aren't otherwise inherited from the parent process. For example, `PS1` is set here because *only* interactive shells care about its value, and any interactive shell will source `.bashrc` anyway, so there is no need to define and export `PS1` from `.profile`.

And though you didn't ask, it's worth pointing out the difference between `.profile` and `.bash_profile` here. `.profile` is "shared" by all POSIX shells (such as `dash`), so don't put anything `bash`-specific here. `.bash_profile`, though, is only used by `bash`, so you can use `bash` extensions in it. If `.bash_profile` is present, `.profile` will be ignored, so if for whatever reason you want to use both, you can add `. ~/.profile` to the top of your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. And I do appreciate the last paragraph. I don't think I have anything bash-specific regarding environment variables, and I do have both ~/.profile and .~/.bash_profile Looks like I have some more poking around to do.

Comment: Mostly, it just means avoiding using things like `[[ ... ]]` in `.profile`.

Comment: No, it's not run for every command you issue in a terminal. It's sourced by `bash` when it is started as an interactive shell (i.e., when its standard input is a terminal or the `-i` option is explicitly used).

Comment: @MDeBusk If you look at the top of the `~/.profile` file, you will see that `~/.profile` is not called by bash if you have a `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @ubfan1 That's `.bashrc` being sourced by `bash`, not `ls`.

Comment: Then something is very wrong with your configuration. `ls` does *not* look for or execute `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Terrance I had somehow overlooked that bit of text. Thank you.

Comment: @chepner I have nothing so interesting in there right now.

Comment: `.bashrc` is also only used by `bash`, but all login shells (`ash`, `csh`, `ksh`, `fish`) use `.profile`.

Comment: Neither `csh` nor `fish` use `.profile`, as they use entirely different syntax.

Answer (score 16):

`~/.profile` is only called when you first log into your account.  Any changes you make after that it would be wise to log out and back in so settings take effect.  `~/.bashrc` is called every time you launch a terminal window.  There is another `profile` file and it is in the `/etc/` directory.  The main difference between the two is that the `/etc/profile` is called when anyone logs into the system, and the `~/.profile` is called when only the user logs in.

If your `export` lines are only used in a terminal session then I would add them to the `~/.bashrc` file as they are only valid during the terminal (bash) session.  But, if you want them to be there with or without a terminal open, add them to the `~/.profile` file, but like @chepner has stated do not put bash specific commands in the `~/.profile` file.

If you screw up these files, there are default files stored in the `/etc/skel/` directory that you can copy back over to your home directory.  Also, the `/etc/skel/` files are also used when you boot to a LiveUSB/CD/DVD, so if you modify those on your live media and then when it completes the boot you can have your own variables set.

Comment: this doesn't seem to the question about setting exported variables in `.profile` vs. in `.bashrc`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't understand what you are asking here.  Please elaborate.  And also, this really is a question that is based more on opinion since it is a preference thing.

Comment: The question seemed to ask about moving exported variables from `.bashrc` to `.profile`, and about the differences between them, or any breakage the move might cause. And I didn't see that addressed in the answer at all. It's true that `~/.profile` is read only for login shells, but what does it mean for the environment variables?

Comment: @ilkkachu I still have no clue what you are talking about.  `~/.profile` is not read only as I can modify it at anytime while I am logged into a system.  As far as exporting lines go, you need to look at what they are used for.  `~/.bashrc` is used during a terminal session only that is running bash.  `~/.profile` is used even by the GUI and terminal sessions and is only called one time at log in.  It really depends on what their export lines are.

Comment: Assuming that your terminal sessions are all started from your login shell (or a descendent thereof), they will inherit any environment variables defined in `.profile`. The key is to understand that it's not terminal windows, per se, that use `.bashrc`, but the interactive non-login shells that they typically run by default.

Comment: On macOS, for example, terminal sessions tend to start login shells, because the terminal emulator itself is not being started from a login shell.

Comment: @chepner I can, and in fact, keep sourcing my `~/.bashrc` file over and over again in a terminal (bash) session and it will duplicate settings over and over again and really mess things up.  But, if I close the session and re-open it, those variables are cleaned up and reset.  Honestly, if you really want, feel free to write your own answer here.

Comment: "~/.profile is only called when you first log into your account." Only if the only login shell you start is the initial shell when you log in.

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't really *intended* to be repeatedly sourced. It's for configuring an interactive shell on start up.

Comment: Original answer was actually better, being less technical and answering the question, i.e., what to put in `.profile` and what in `.bashrc`, more directly.

Comment: @vanadium Do you think I should just go back to the original answer with a few changes added?

Comment: Actually, yes, although in the mean time, chepner filled the gap very nicely.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you!  :)  And, done!

Comment: Upvoted. It is now to the OP to choose ;)

Comment: @vanadium It's a bit of a shame that "there can be only one!"

Comment: @MDeBusk I am OK with anyway that you choose.  I am here to help.  :-)

Answer (score 12):

[chepner's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411917/354600) covers the overall principles. There are a few other subtleties that you want to take note of.

First, login shells do *not* source `.bashrc` even if they are interactive. Thus, you probably want a `.bash_profile` that contains code like the following:

```
interactive() { [[ $- = *i* ]]; }
interactive && . $HOME/.bashrc || echo 1>&2 "ERROR: .bashrc failed with retval $?"
```

This won't make much difference on a console login into a graphical environment, but will make quite a difference on a text console or ssh login.

You don't necessarily need to do the interactive test; I actually source `.bashrc` even for non-interactive shells (though this is arguably not a good idea in some circumstances).

Note that if you use non-Bash shells as well, you'll also need a `.profile` with whatever environment variables etc. you want for those. Bash will ignore your `.profile` when you have a `.bash_profile`, but of course the latter can source the former.

---

Not every fresh login (i.e., a shell created not by your user id but by a root process that has authenticated you) is considered a "login shell." In particular, giving a command to an ssh invocation (`ssh somehost.example.com 'echo $-'`) will *not* be a "login shell" and `.bash_profile`/`.bash_login`/`.profile` will not be sourced. Here's a table showing what's considered a "login" or interactive shell and what's executed for various invocations

| State | Invocation |
| --- | --- |
| Login (**L**) | `argv[0][0] == '-'`, `--login` |
| Interactive (**I**) | `-i`, stdin is tty |
| Remote (**R**) | stdin is "network connection" (see below) |

- '•' = set; blank = not set; '-' = not checked or don't care.
- **inh**: Inherits environment from a parent (other than init);
  i.e., it's not a "fresh login" and the parent may expect that
  the environment be kept intact.
- **p**: sources `/etc/profile`
  then first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`
- **rc**: sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` then `~/.bashrc`

| L | I | R |  | inh | p | rc |  | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| • | • | - |  |  | • |  |  | `ssh host.com` (sshd sets argv[0]="-bash") |
| • |  | - |  |  | • |  |  | `ssh host.com </dev/null` (sshd sets argv[0]="-bash") |
|  | • |  |  | • |  | • |  | `bash -i`, `bash` on tty |
|  |  |  |  | • |  |  |  | `bash hello.sh`, `bash -c echo foo`, |
|  |  | • |  |  |  | • |  | `ssh host.com 'echo $-'` (ssh runs `bash -c 'echo $-`) |

The table comes from [this document](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/lang/bash/init.md); there's some further information there that might also be useful. (Anybody who feels something there should be in this answer should feel free to edit this and copy it in.)

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know this about ssh sessions. Thank you.