# .bash_profile guidance

Tags: bash, bashrc, .profile

I want to know if there is any guidance I should be following somewhere (maybe from a man page or something) regarding creation of a `~/.bash_profile`.  By default Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have one, it just has a `.profile` file.  As I understand it, `.profile` should just be executing `~/.bashrc`.  Thus my assumption is that I just need to add a line at the end of my `~.bash_profile` to execute `~/.bashrc` ; something like:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

The reason I ask is because if I create this file, then my .profile file will not be called, so I just need to make sure I'm doing it right.

Second part of my question is, am I correct in understanding `~/.bash_profile` should only be invoked ONCE during my login, and then that's it (i.e. sub-sequent interactive shells will just invoke only `/etc/bash.bashrc` followed by `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I'm just learning.  No goal in sight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What goes in ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411833/what-goes-in-profile-and-bashrc)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar questions about six months ago and got some excellent guidance. Please refer to [my question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411833/what-goes-in-profile-and-bashrc).

I ended up putting in `~/.bashrc` everything I needed for working at the command line and putting everything else in `~/.profile`. I source `~/.bashrc` at the top of `~/.profile` *and* `~/.bash_profile`.

If you'd like to look over [the current incarnation of my dotfiles](https://github.com/mdebusk/dotfiles), such as they are, you're welcome to do so. They're reasonably well-organized (I think) and well-commented.

Comment: Why would you keep a `.bash_profile` file only to have it source `.profile`? `.profile` will always be sourced by any shell instance that would read `.bash_profile`, _unless_ `.bash_profile` exists. So you are creating a file that isn't needed only to have it do exactly what would happen if you hadn't created the file in the first place. Just delete your `.bash_profile` and you will be in the same situation you are in now.

Comment: @terdon I have no explanation for that. My best guess is that I did it before I understood fully what was going on. As it's not drawn any attention to itself, I've left it alone. I'll consider removing it.