# How to share bash aliases between non-root user bash and shell opened by "sudo -i"?

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc, alias, .profile

I'm used to use `sudo -i` and don't have a `root` password set, i.e. `su -` doesn't work. I'm looking for a way to share `bash` aliases between a user shell (e.g. the one opened when I start `gnome-terminal` started as the user who logged into the display manager) and the shell opened by `sudo -i`.

According to `man sudo` it's a login shell and afaik it should source `~/.profile`, i.e. `/root/.profile`, but putting aliases in `/root/.profile` doesn't work. Only if I run `bash` in the shell opened by `sudo -i` the alias is available. According to `/etc/passwd` `root`'s shell is `bash` and `SHELL` variable confirms that (in the shell started by `sudo -i`).

I'd prefer to not put the aliases in `/etc/profile` because that would expose them to any user and I only want to have them for the display manager user and `root`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related [Serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/q/335769/363611) suggests using `/etc/bashrc`, but I personally would recommend creating `/etc/shell_aliases` file ( apparently `/etc/aliases` [by sendmail package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65013/85039) is already reserved ) , and source it from your user's and root users `.bashrc` file. That way you can re-define aliases globally.

Alternative approach as shown in this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/q/610052/295286) is to use `/etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh`.

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo alias print_hello=\"echo 'HELLO\ ASKUBUNTU'\" > /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh  ' 
$ sudo -i
$ print_hello
HELLO ASKUBUNTU
```

**Side note:** for GUI shells , you will have to log out and log in, because `.profile` is sourced each time you log in, and once you sing into the system via graphical login screen, it will be sourced , but only once. All terminal emulators opened are considered interactive shells after that.

Comment: I just figured that neither `/etc/bashrc` nor `/root/.profile` is read, i.e. alias isn't available which I think is a bug. Adding to `/etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh` works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Open your root `.bashrc` file and edit the `bash_aliases` function.

Change:

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

to

```bsh
if [ -f /home/[username]/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . /home/[username]/.bash_aliases 
fi
```