# Alias for all users

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, alias

I created a this file: `/etc/profile.d/pycharm_alias.sh`

```
startPyCharm() {...

}

alias py=startPyCharm
```

I rebooted the PC, but then the alias is not available:

```
===> alias
...empty
```

If I login to the PC via ssh the alias is available:

```
===> ssh root@localhost
..
root@pc:~# alias
alias py='startPyCharm'
```

How to make an alias available for all users of a ubuntu linux system?

We use the bash shell.

Comment: You have answered your own question, and in the answer you seem satisfied. Please explain what you want beyond the answer of that solution? For example, do you want to know where to put the shellscript? And how to do it?

Comment: @sudodus I found a work-around (don't use an alias), but no real solution. The question is still answered: How to make an alias available for all users of a ubuntu linux system? Fiddling with /etc/bash.bashrc is error-prone since I would like to avoid that several tools change one file.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation :-) Honestly, I think that aliases are intended for personal use (and should reside in each user's `~/.bashrc` file). I'll try to find a method to make it work to globally change an alias (but I cannot see a way right now). I think using a shellscript and put it in a directory, that is in "everybody's path" is a good way to do it. So I think your answer really contains a good solution, and not 'just a workaround'. For this reason I will upvote it ;-)

Comment: See: [Understanding .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121413/understanding-bashrc-and-bash-profile/606882#606882)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want an alias for all users?

Why not create a executable script?

A script is simpler and can be used from all shell, not just bash.

At least in my case using a script instead of an alias solved my issue.

BTW: This is just a work-around, not a real solution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try putting this in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. It's stated purpose is `# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.` Which seems like it may be what you want. I am surprised that your profile.d solution did not work.

Comment: Does creating a file in /etc/profile.d/ work for you?

Comment: I use `/etc/skel` which is copied into the user's home directory when they are created. This would not work for existing users

Comment: I know `/etc/skel`, but sometimes you want to change something after a user was created.

Comment: I would like to avoid changing `/etc/bash.bashrc` since it is error-prone if several tools change this single file.

Answer (score 1):

## Aliases are personal tools

- I think aliases are intended for personal use (and should reside in each user's `~/.bashrc` file).

## Shellscripts (and other programs) are general tools

- Make a shellscript and put it in a directory, that is in "everybody's path".

  - But it is important to be careful in order to avoid overwriting existing programs or putting existing programs in shadow. You may put the shellscript before an existing program in path, so that the system will not find it via `PATH`.

    In other words, *make sure that the name is unique* to avoid problems with other programs.

#### Detailed tips

This is my path in Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/sudodus/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I have an own `bin` directory, which is automatically found and put in the beginning of the path (with highest priority). But the rest of the path is standard.

I would suggest that you

- check that there should be no conflict with the name

  ```
  type unique-name  # shows if it exists and what kind of program it is
  which unique-name # shows where an installed program is stored 
  unique-name       # if known but not installed, you get a hint about it
  apt-cache policy *unique-name*  # package name (may or may not be same as program name)
  ```
- if no conflict, create a shellscript (this is a trivial example)

  ```
  echo 'echo "Hello World"' > unique-name
  ```
- make the shellscript executable

  ```
  chmod +x unique-name
  ```
- put the shellscript into `/usr/local/sbin` if it needs root privileges or otherwise into `/usr/local/bin`.

  ```
  sudo cp -i unique-name /usr/local/bin
  ```

  The option `-i` prompts you if the name already exists in the target directory.

#### How all users can run your shellscript

When you make the shellscript executable and it is in a directory in everybody's `PATH`, everybody can run it via its file name,

```
unique-name
```

There are several short strings that are not yet used as names for standard programs, and you can find such names by testing with

```
type short-string-to-be-tested
```

for example

```
$ type py
bash: type: py: not found
```

In my computer there is no executable program and no shell built-in with that name, so I can use `py` as a file name (and I need no alias).

But if you try to run `py` before renaming your shellscript to that name,

```
$ py

Command 'py' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install pythonpy
```

you will find that there is such a program (but it is not yet installed), and it might be a good idea to select another name, for example

```
pych
```

which can be a short name derived from your original name PyCharm.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/830074/best-directory-to-place-my-bash-scripts

Answer (score 1):

### Why the global `alias` deosn't work

One reason the global `alias` doesn't work is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610052/how-can-i-preset-aliases-for-all-users#comment857717_610079):

> The method in this answer should not be used. Aliases in `.sh` files
>   in `/etc/profile.d/` (or `/etc/profile`) will be defined only for
>   login shells and they will not work in interactive non-login shells.
>   Unlike environment variables, bash can't export aliases to child
>   processes, not even child bash shells. This method may seem to work
>   properly if it's only tested in login shells, such as the original
>   shell obtained by logging on in a virtual console or via SSH, but [it
>   fails in their child shells](https://paste.ubuntu.com/10841694/) and also fails in shells started by
>   GUI terminal windows. – [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) Apr 18 '15 at 0:56

---

## Use a global function in `/etc/profile.d`

Currently you have `/etc/profile.d/pycharm_alias.sh` containing:

```bash
startPyCharm() {...

}

alias py=startPyCharm
```

Assigning an global alias to a function isn't necesssary. You could simply create a global function called `py` that does what `StartPyCharm` does.

For example, create `/etc/profile.d/py.sh` containing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

py () {
    echo "Running py function in /etc/profile.d/py.sh"
    echo "Substitute for py alias which calls StartPyCharm function"
}

export -f py
```

Replace the `echo` commands with the contents of your current `StartPyCharm ()` function.

When a user logs in and opens the shell they can type `py` and a global function is called instead of a global alias to a function.

To see all your functions (both global and local) use `declare -F`

Comment: +1: good explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just navigate to `/etc/bash.bashrc` by typing:

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

You then insert the following code after the first #Comment:

```
alias py='startPyCharm'
```

Then you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd>, and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then, in the Console, type only `bash` and you're ready to go.
If you just wish to set the command to a certain account, use the same steps except for the path, which must be `/home/<user>/.bashrc`.