# Where does `bashrc` run under during the boot process

Tags: bashrc

`.bashrc` could be reloaded by executing command `source .bashrc` after do some modifications.

Under this situation, command `source .bashrc`, the instructions in `bashrc` running in under  the `gnome-terminal`

```
$ pstree -asp $$
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,2626 --user
      └─gnome-terminal-,5398
          └─bash,5507
              └─pstree,5690 -asp 5507
```

How about the `bashrc` in the boot process?

is it running under a terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.bashrc` file is not executed and will not show up as a process.  Since it is a file, you can use tools to detect reads and writes.

When your shell (e.g. `bash`) starts up, it 'sources' files.  This means that it opens and reads the file, and runs any commands in the file.  The shell process itself does this, and as you're likely aware, this allows you to set up different environment variables, aliases, functions, etc.

There are other, similar files. `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` all having slight technical differences, but similar functionality.  You can see [this great explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/606882/13247) and example of `.bash_profile` vs `.bashrc`.  There are usually user-specific files in each user's home directory, and system configs in `/etc/`, such as `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

So, `.bashrc` is never executed, but instead *sourced* each time you start a new shell terminal spawns, or whenever you manually source the file: `source ~/.bashrc`.