# Where is .bashrc?

Tags: command-line, configuration, bashrc, hidden-files

I feel stupid asking, but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=614743) to edit my bash prompt, but there is no `.bashrc` in either my user directory (`~/.bashrc`), or in my home directory, or in the main file system directory.

There is no `.bashrc` in `/etc/` (there is a `bash.bashrc`, however).

Do I create a `.bashrc` file in my user or home directory? Is there a better, more recent set of instructions for modifying the bash prompt?

Comment: You do not need to find/edit .bashrc in `/etc/`. There should be a *.bashrc* file in your home directory. Try to open/edit `~/.bashrc`. But before that I should also ask if you are new to Linux. If you are new to Linux, then I can post detailed instructions here.

Comment: All of the above answers recommend putting your aliases in `.bashrc`, but [you should put them in `.bash_profile`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121413/undertanding-bashrc-and-bash-profile) **Edit** To clarify, don't create a `.bashrc` if it's just for this, create or modify `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Louis Defining aliases in `.bash_profile` is wrong. In Ubuntu `.profile` (which runs for login shells) sources `.bashrc` when it's an interactive bash shell. So putting aliases in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`, sourced in `.bashrc`) defines them in *all* interactive bash shells. Aliases in `.bash_profile` yields [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/109985), and others. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536), [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414), [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/606882), and the default `~/.bashrc`'s comments recommending putting aliases there or in `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm very sorry if I've misled anyone. I wrote that comment just a few months into using Linux. Peculiarly I do now have them in `.bashrc` and sourced my `.bashrc` in `.bash_profile` with code copied from [this SuperUser answer](http://superuser.com/a/163268/244556) ("*Get the aliases and functions*"). Thanks for correcting these commonly viewed questions Eliah, [really nice answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/606882/266014)!

Comment: Answer for similar question for Windows is  here [Git for Windows: .bashrc or equivalent config files for Git Bash shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883798)

Comment: Here is one highly related topic: [At what point is the ~/.bashrc file created?](https://askubuntu.com/q/971836/566421)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Don't forget it is a hidden file inside your home directory (you would not be the first to do a `ls -l` and thinking it is not there).

Do a:

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

There should be a `.bashrc` on the first page.
If not just create it with:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and add in the lines you need to add into it.

Permissions of my `.bashrc` are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 discworld discworld  3330 Mar 10 16:03 .bashrc
```

(`chmod 644 .bashrc` to make it `rw r r`).

Comment: That was exactly it -- hidden file, and I didn't think to look beyond the obvious. Thanks -- maybe this will help other shmucks like me as well. :)

Comment: I don't seem to get the `sudo...` line, isn't this `touch ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Rinzwind I think that line still has an extra dot in the filename.

Comment: No, there was no extra dot! I deny there to have been 2 errors in that command! :=D

Comment: Sorry, my bad! :P

Comment: lol @igarzo :D :D

Comment: There definitely is no `sudo`, just edit it with `vi ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: There still is no `.bashrc` for me, even a hidden one.  There is a template in `/etc/skel/` though; type `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` to use it.

Comment: You can also view all the files (including the hidden ones) by using the following command: ll

Comment: Can I have it in `~/.config/bash/bashrc`?

Answer (score 44):

**User specific**, hidden by default.

```
~/.bashrc
```

If not there simply create one.

**System wide**:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 17):

There is a .bashrc in every user's home folder (99.99% of the time) as well as one system-wide (which I don't know the location of in Ubuntu).

The quickest way to access it is `nano ~/.bashrc` from a terminal (replace `nano` with whatever you like to use).

If this is not present in a user's home folder the system-wide `.bashrc` is used as a fallback as it is loaded before the user's file. You could simply copy and paste it (with root permissions of course), but a `.bashrc` is not entirely essential (it may be required to make things work. I haven't found out) at a user level as it mostly overrides the system-wide one with user-specific tweaks. You could write your own though.

The main components for that users may tweak are `PS1` (the Bash prompt defaults to display `user@localhost:pwd $`) and aliases as well as setting a color prompt and maybe `PS2` (busy state message).

Answer (score 14):

Use `gedit ~/.bashrc`, it will allow you to modify `~/.bashrc` using gedit.

Comment: This is so much easier, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It is hidden because of the '.' it starts with.

list it with

`ls -al`

or enable "show hidden files" under the view menu in nautilus (Ctrl-H will also do the trick).

You can edit it with your favorite text editor from your home directory e.g.

`cd`

to go to your home directory then:

`emacs .bashrc`

Comment: You can even just use `ls -a`

Answer (score 5):

If `.bashrc` is not in your home folder, even after you list the hidden files, you can copy it from:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

if not in home directory, you can just copy from `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and make it source for your terminal, by typing in your terminal `source .bashrc` from your home directory after copying.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nano ~/.bashrc` to open and edit the .bashrc file. (This will create the file if it does not yet exist)

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to edit your own `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

If you use encryption and work from the command line you might not see it as one need to mount the real home-dir first (in contrast to in the graphical UI where this is done automaticallu) by the command:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

(I had the same question and stumbled upon this question; but found *my* answer in the readme instead)

Answer (score 0):

Bashrc file  is a hidden file inside the home directory. It is actually, give the path directions.

And those are wanted to edit `.bashrc` file, try this command `gedit ~/.bashrc` instead of this `~/.bashrc` .

This command `gedit ~/.bashrc` directly take you to the text editor, where you can edit it easily, as you know.

Answer (score 0):

Just one note: after you made your alias in bashrc, you need in your terminal to write following command in order that your aliases work:

```
source .bashrc
```

Personally, whenever I install Linux anew, I add some aliases finding an appropriate place in .bashrc
E.g.

```
#My aliases
alias shut='shutdown now'
alias x='exit'
alias update='sudo apt-get update'
```

Etc. You get the idea.